# Different Behavior when running nunit tests from project and from solution

Tags: entity-framework, nunit, resharper

I have various projects in a Solution with many tests, one of them use entities and has the following behaviour:
If I right click run all tests on my project everything runs smoothly but if I right click on my solution and does the same I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file.

I have of course those lines in my App.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Sales.csdl|res://*/Sales.ssdl|res://*/Sales.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\louis gentil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TFS\LouisGentil\SQL\ModuleSQL-Database.mdf&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
```

More info asked by kif:

- It is in Visual Studio
- I use resharper as a unit tester
- I don't know if test project compile into an app, I don't thnk so it is just a class library I use for test.
- It has it's own app.config indeed.
- The above error is when I right click on my solution and ask resharper to run the unit test nomatter what project is the startup project.

Do you have any idea about what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: We need some more information. Is this Visual Studio? Do you use the Test Runner? Does your test project compile into an app? With its own app.config? Which is where you have the above lines defined? And when you run it from the solution, which project is the startup project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have edited my question to answer as many question as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting "Use separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests" in ReSharper → Options → Unit Testing. This is an optimisation ReSharper makes that reuses AppDomains (they're expensive to set up), but has the side effect that only one app.config can be loaded, and it might be the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks , works like a charm ! It was nothing but still it bugged me like hell!